# What Bugs are common in Wheat & spelt?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, bugs, yoreh-deah, chulin-tractate

BH

I know one of the common insects found in lettuce are called aphids although what are the common bugs found in Wheat & Spelt? My teacher told me to watch out for little black dots on them perhaps because they could eat through into the core so what to watch out for when checking?